# CodeIgniter - vBulletin integration

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, integration, vbulletin

I have an external Codeigniter project, and I need to read session from a vBulletin project. I read a lot but I don't get a solution.

From my CI project, on index.php, I put this:

```
chdir('/Path/to/vBulletin/Project/www');
require_once('./global.php');
```

where the global.php is. For what I read, this should read the session. I print the $vBulletin->userinfo object, but I always get the userid = NULL, and the username "Unregistered". Thanks

Comment: The problem with CI and a lot of famous systems (like WordPress and forum systems) is that they will want to dominate on the use of cookies and sessions. I've had this fight with CI and WordPress. Trust me, stop now and move them fully apart from each other with an extra piece of interface-code between both systems. I can assure you you will be a very sad person in a month or three if you try to merge them into one and another.

Comment: I'm sure it's a better way, but since everybody says it works I thought it would be a faster solution. I just need to know if it is logged in or not. Thanks for your reply